# connecting to sql database in java

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to connect to a database. My friend wrote this code but isn't working. It is not showing any errors.

The name of the database is testdb and table name is tab. It is in the same folder where the code is.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class dbtest {
 public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:testdb");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
    stat.executeQuery("insert into tab values ('test','test','test')");
        //stat.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dbtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(dbtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working? What do you expect to see? What do you actually see?

Comment: Why borrow a "friend's" code? Why not go through the [Java database tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) and learn to write your own, one that actually displays some results?

Comment: @Steve McLeod : the values are not getting inserted to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your odbc connection

goto ControlPanel->AdministrativeTools->DataSource(ODBC)->System DSN->ADD->SqlServer->

then in the name field give the Source Name.

you have to use this name instead of testdb in your DriverManager.getConnection method.

Because getConnectionMethod take the source name not the database name. so your code is not working.

However after filling the source name fill the server field with your server.Then you will be asked to bind the database for the source connection and set your database name.Hopefully you are done.

Answer (score 0):

All the errors are being put into the Logger object so you won't see them immediately.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html

In order to get it working, you should look at a JDBC tutorial.