# java.sql.SQLException: General error at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

I'm trying to establish a JDBC-ODBC connection using the following routine,

```
private static Connection getConnection(String systemDSN, String username, String password) throws Exception {
    String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + systemDSN;
    Class.forName(driver);
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

And here's the complete stack trace I'm getting!

```
java.sql.SQLException: General error at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone PLEASE let me know how this is caused and how I can remedy this??!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477887/connecting-to-sql-database-in-java/6477983#6477983

Comment: But I'm sure I'm using the System DSN names rather than the database names.  I in fact read through the registry to derive the appropriate System DSN name for that matter.  Could you please give me any other suggestions??!

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if this could be yet another bitness issue?

If this is a 64bit system then the bitness of the Java runtime is important!!!!

64bit Java run time will only be able to access 64bit ODBC drivers...

32bit Java run time will only be able to access 32bit ODBC drivers...

32bit and 64bit ODBC environments are not the same...

Comment: It ended up to be the wrong username and password!  How annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the answer for "general error" I finally found that it is the problem on the data source name.

`jdbc:odbc:xx` where `xx` is the data source name NOT the data base name

It works form me!